# Why do I get "assigning to 'int *' from incompatible type 'void *' " error?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm learning c on codeacademy and I get an *assigning to 'int *' from incompatible type 'void *'* error. My file is a .c file, which includes stdlib.h. I don't understand the error, it seems that the corrections uses the same lines of code.

I'm trying to create an array using malloc.

I tried to find the answer on other topics. It seems that malloc is not the best way to do it but i would like to find a way to make it work.

I'm on a mac, I use emacs to code et gcc to compile.

Here's a part of my code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char mot_secret[] = "PISCINE";
  int nombre_lettres = strlen(mot_secret);
  int *pnombre_lettres = &nombre_lettres;
  int *decouverte = NULL;
  int compteur = 10;

  decouverte = malloc(nombre_lettres * sizeof(int));
  if (decouverte == NULL)
    {
      exit(0);
    }
```

And here's the solution : 
( I tried to translate some of the variables)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char lettre = 0;
    char secretword[100] = {0};
    int *lettreTrouvee = NULL; 
    long coupsRestants = 10; // Compteur de coups restants (0 = mort)
    long i = 0;
    long wordSize = 0;

    wordSize = strlen(secretWord);

    lettreTrouvee = malloc(tailleMot * sizeof(int)); // creates a dynamic array of the size of the original)
    if (lettreTrouvee == NULL)
        exit(0);
```

The error is :

```
TP.C:17:16: error: assigning to 'int *' from incompatible type 'void *'
  decouverte = malloc(nombre_lettres * sizeof(int));
```

Thank you very much for your help and I'm sorry if I make any mistakes in English.

Comment: Perhaps you are compiling it with a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very quick answer.

I compiled my file like this : gcc -o tp tp.c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that your file's name is `TP.C`.

In the unix tradition, C source files are named `*.c` (lowercase c), and C++ source files are named `*.C` (capital C). The alternative `*.cpp` is used on Windows because of its case-ignorant filesystem, but gcc on MacOS is sufficiently unix-like that it is treating your `*.C` file as C++.

Comment: But when I look in the Finder, the file is called " TP.c" but in the error it's called " TP.C" and to create it, I did " emacs TP.c" (in lowercase).
Is it possible that it is a ".C" file but the finder shows it as a '.c" file ?

Comment: You can force gcc to treat the file as C language by using the option `-x c`. (It overrides language auto-detection for any source filename parameters that follow.)

Comment: It shows a " .c " file, 

Here's the ls command : 
macbook-pro-de-florian:CODEACADEMY Florian$ ls
OLD TP.c

Thank you @IanAbbott, I didn't know a to force gcc to compile the file in C

Comment: @FlorianOry Perhaps the file can be found with both names `TP.c` and `TP.C`. Which name is used on the compiler command line? The error messages imply it is compiling `TP.C`. Does `ls TP.C` show a matched filename? Does `cat TP.C` list the file contents?

Comment: @FlorianOry, does Ian's suggestion to force C-language mode resolve your problem?  If so, then both of your current positive-scoring answers are correct.  The remaining issues would then seem to be about the semantics of your filesystem, and those would be better raised as a separate question (if you cannot readily find an answer through your own research).

Comment: @IanAbbott, and John Bollinger ( I can only tag 1 person), the ls and cat commands show a matched file for TP.c and TP.C. It seems that TP.C is an hidden file. But when I compiled I used the TP.c . It works when I force the C resolve mode. And I also tried to create a new tp2.c file with the same content and I worked too. I don't know how the TP.C file was created but your solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much for you help !!

Comment: The error says how the compiler _sees_ the file.  So try to rename the file, as it is compiling it as a c++ file.

Answer (score 8):

Given this error message:

> ```
> TP.C:17:16: error: assigning to 'int *' from incompatible type 'void *'
>   decouverte = malloc(nombre_lettres * sizeof(int));
> ```

it appears your file is named `TP.C`.  [The upper-case `.C` file extension causes GCC to compile the file as C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options):

> ```
> file.cc
> file.cp
> file.cxx
> file.cpp
> file.CPP
> file.c++
> file.C
> ```
>
> C++ source code that must be preprocessed. Note that in ‘.cxx’, the last two > must both be literally ‘x’. **Likewise, ‘.C’ refers to a literal capital C.**

You need to use lower-case.  Rename your file so that it ends with a `.c` - lower-case `c`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, an hidden file TP.C was in the folder

Answer (score -9):

The type returned from malloc is always void*, which can be cast to the desired type of data.

You will need to do:
(int*) malloc(nombre_lettres * sizeof(int));

source: [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Comment: Your answer is valid for C++, but frowned upon in C.

Comment: Hi Marian. This question is tagged [c], not [c++] ... they are different languages and have different rules for use of `malloc`. This is actually the key to the OP's problem, which turns out to be rather fascinating ... see the discussion above under Wumpus Q. Wumbley's answer.